# Oracle group by Alias

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions, min

Orale is returning an error in the group by using alias column.

```
SELECT  
    CONCAT( CONCAT( a.air_location, ' ,' ), a.air_code ) AS "Departs From",
    CONCAT( CONCAT( ad.air_location, ' ,' ), ad.air_code ) AS "Arrives At",
    MIN(f.fl_fare) AS "Minimun Fare" 
FROM flight f
INNER JOIN airport a ON a.air_code = f.fl_dest
INNER JOIN airport ad ON ad.air_code = f.fl_orig
GROUP BY "Departs From", "Arrives At";
```

It is returning:

```
ORA-00904: "Arrives At": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 10 Column: 26
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a column alias in the `GROUP BY` clause in Oracle - and positional parameters are not supported either. You need to repeat the expression, or use a subquery or cte. So:

```
select  
    ao.air_location || ' ,' || ao.air_code as departs_from,
    ad.air_location || ' ,' || ad.air_code as arrives_at,
    min(f.fl_fare) as minimun_fare
from flight f
inner join airport ad on ad.air_code = f.fl_dest
inner join airport ao on ao.air_code = f.fl_orig
group by 
    ao.air_location || ' ,' || ao.air_code
    ad.air_location || ' ,' || ad.air_code
```

Other changes to your query:

- changed table aliases to names that seem more meaningful to me (and I think you had the origin and destination inverted in the result)
- used standard ANSI string concatenation operator `||` instead of `CONCAT()`, which Oracle supports
- used column aliases that do not require quoting (without embedded spaces), because it makes the query easier to write - you can revert that change if you really want otherwise.

As a final thought: here is an alternative that uses a lateral join to generate the aliases:

```
select x.departs_from, x.arrives_at, min(f.fl_fare) as minimun_fare
from flight f
inner join airport ad on ad.air_code = f.fl_dest
inner join airport ao on ao.air_code = f.fl_orig
cross apply (
    select 
        ao.air_location || ' ,' || ao.air_code as departs_from,
        ad.air_location || ' ,' || ad.air_code as arrives_at
    from dual
) x
group by x.departs_from, x.arrives_at
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your CONCAT query up in a *derived table*, `GROUP BY` its result:

```
SELECT "Departs From", "Arrives At", MIN(fl_fare) as minimun_fare
FROM
(
    SELECT  
        CONCAT( CONCAT( a.air_location, ' ,' ), a.air_code ) AS "Departs From",
        CONCAT( CONCAT( ad.air_location, ' ,' ), ad.air_code ) AS "Arrives At",
        f.fl_fare
    FROM flight f
    INNER JOIN airport a ON a.air_code = f.fl_dest
    INNER JOIN airport ad ON ad.air_code = f.fl_orig
) dt
GROUP BY "Departs From", "Arrives At";
```

(The GROUP BY is evaluated before the SELECT list. So the column aliases can't be used in the GROUP BY since they don't yet exist.)